# Using name full name and maiden name strings (and birthdays) to match individuals across time

Tags: r, data.table

I've got a set of 20 or so consecutive individual-level cross-sectional data sets which I would like to link together.

Unfortunately, there's no time-stable ID number; there are, however, fields for first, last, and maiden names, as well as year of birth--this should allow for a pretty high (90-95%) match rate, I presume.

Ideally, I would create a time-independent ID for each unique individual.

I can do this for those whose marital status (maiden name) does not change pretty easily in R--stack the data sets to get a long panel, then do something to the effect of:

```
unique(dt,by=c("first_name","last_name","birth_year"))[,id:=.I]
```

(I'm of course using R `data.table`), then merging back to the full data.

However, I'm stuck on how to incorporate the maiden name to this procedure. Any suggestions?

Here's a preview of the data:

```
       first_name     last_name       nee birth_year year
    1:     eileen      aaldxxxx     dxxxx       1977 2002
    2:     eileen      aaldxxxx     dxxxx       1977 2003
    3:      sarah        aaxxxx    gexxxx       1974 2003
    4:      kelly        aaxxxx     nxxxx       1951 2008
    5:      linda aarxxxx-gxxxx   aarxxxx       1967 2008
   ---                                                   
72008:     stacey      zwirxxxx   kruxxxx       1982 2010
72009:     stacey      zwirxxxx   kruxxxx       1982 2011
72010:     stacey      zwirxxxx   kruxxxx       1982 2012
72011:     stacey      zwirxxxx   kruxxxx       1982 2013
72012:       jill      zydoxxxx gundexxxx       1978 2002
```

---

UPDATE:

I've done a lot of chipping and hammering at the problem; here's what I've got so far. I would appreciate any comments for possible improvements to the code so far.

I'm still completely missing something like 3-5% of matches due to inexact matches (`"tonya"` vs. `"tanya"`, `"jenifer"` vs. `"jennifer"`); I haven't come up with a clean way of doing fuzzy matching on the stragglers, so there's room for better matching in that direction if anyone's got a straightforward way to implement that.

The basic approach is to build cumulatively--assign IDs in the first year, then look for matches in the second year; assign new IDs to the unmatched. Then for year 3, look back at the first 2 years, etc. As to how to match, the idea is to slowly expand the matching criteria--the idea being that the more robust the match, the lower the chances of mismatching accidentally (particularly worried about the `John Smith`s).

Without further ado, here's the main function for matching a pair of data sets:

```
get_id<-function(yr,key_from,key_to=key_from,
                 mdis,msch,mard,init,mexp,step){
  #Want to exclude anyone who is matched
  existing_ids<-full_data[.(yr),unique(na.omit(teacher_id))]
  #Get the most recent prior observation of all
  #  unmatched teachers, excluding those teachers
  #  who cannot be uniquely identified by the
  #  current key setting
  unmatched<-
    full_data[.(1996:(yr-1))
              ][!teacher_id %in% existing_ids,
                .SD[.N],by=teacher_id,
                .SDcols=c(key_from,"teacher_id")
                ][,if (.N==1L) .SD,keyby=key_from
                  ][,(flags):=list(mdis,msch,mard,init,mexp,step)]
  #Merge, reset keys
  setkey(setkeyv(
    full_data,key_to)[year==yr&is.na(teacher_id),
                      (update_cols):=unmatched[.SD,update_cols,with=F]],
    year)
  full_data[.(yr),(update_cols):=lapply(.SD,function(x)na.omit(x)[1]),
                                        by=id,.SDcols=update_cols]
}
```

Then I basically go through the 19 years `yy` in a `for` loop, running 12 progressively looser matches, e.g. step 3 is:

```
get_id(yy,c("first_name_clean","last_name_clean","birth_year"),
       mdis=T,msch=T,mard=F,init=F,mexp=F,step=3L)
```

---

The final step is to assign new IDs:

```
current_max<-full_data[.(yy),max(teacher_id,na.rm=T)]
new_ids<-
  setkey(full_data[year==yy&is.na(teacher_id),.(id=unique(id))
                   ][,add_id:=.I+current_max],id)
setkey(setkey(full_data,id)[year==yy&is.na(teacher_id),
                            teacher_id:=new_ids[.SD,add_id]],year)
```

Comment: Can u `dput` at least a part of your dataframe (modifying names if need be)?

Comment: too big for `dput`, just included standard output

Comment: So is the maiden name the part of last_name that's in parentheses, or the column "nee" - and then your problem would be to deal with missing data on that column...?

Comment: updated the data cut to make clear the role of `nee`. i also found, in the 2001 data set, an individual named `eileen dxxxx`, `nee` missing, with the same birth year--i.e., i should surely be able to track marriage formation within the data set.

Comment: Hmmm so you might need to create an intermediate dataframe to sort out the cases with name changes... Seems that some manual checking might be unavoidable...?

Comment: do you have something specific in mind? the approach i have in mind for now is to just try and match consecutive years, only trying to assign a grand id after all matches, retirements/switches & marriages are accounted for from consecutive years. any suggested improvements/caveats there?

Comment: I'm not used to working with `data.table`; I know its `unique` function doesn't work like the base `unique`, so that's one thing to be aware of. Then intuitively, I think I'd make dataframes with unique persons (c.g. `unique(dt[,c("first_name","last_name","nee","birth_year")])`) for every dataframe , and then merge all of those dataframes by all variables. Then maybe use `locf` for maiden names (going backward in time). Next, I'd make a unique ID from this dataframe and propagate it to all individual dataframes. Finally, I would concatenate/rbind all dataframes into one and do my analysis.

Comment: Having so many similar calls (setkey, join, update) I would write some simple helpers and operate on it just passing the vector of column names.

Comment: @jangorecki thanks for looking at this! I haven't updated this in a while; indeed that's what i'm doing now.

Comment: @jangorecki that said, it _is_ rather slow (at least relative to what I'm used to with `data.table`) having to re-`key` my data about 700 times throughout the process. Do you think it may be worth porting this to `pandas` for efficiency?

Comment: I don't know pandas, but once [data.table#1130](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1130) will be implemented you should not need to re-setkey anymore.

Comment: @jangorecki sadly the process took 10 minutes longer (~30%) with the help of the newly-implemented `on`!

Comment: @MichaelChirico what you are saying looks like an issue to report on github project

Comment: @jangorecki indeed, I'm going to explore & make sure it's true in a vacuum (I also changed a few other things I thought were minor since last timing, but perhaps they weren't). thanks.