# Using a merge to define a subset of a data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I'm using multiple merges to define an ID variable in R (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29176114/using-name-full-name-and-maiden-name-strings-and-birthdays-to-match-individual) question for more context).

I want to merge variable `v` from `data.table` `x` to `data.table` `y` first according to, say, keys `k1` in `y`.

Then for those observations that weren't matched in the first stage, I want to merge them according to table `y` keys `k2`.

```
y[is.na(v),x,v:=v]
```

doesn't work, as `data.table` syntax expects a `data.table` first when merging.

```
y[is.na(v),][x,v:=v]
```

works in a sense, but doesn't save the results of the merge to `y`.

Here's a minimal example:

```
x<-data.table(v1=c("A","B","C"),v2=c("a","b","c"),v=rnorm(3),key=c("v1","v2"))
y<-data.table(v1=c("A","B","C"),v21=c("","b","c"),v22=c("a","",""))
setkey(y,v1,v21)
y[x,v:=v]
```

gives

```
> x
   v1 v2          v
1:  A  a  0.3316665
2:  B  b  0.8470424
3:  C  c -0.5955292
> y
   v1 v21 v22          v
1:  A       a         NA
2:  B   b      0.8470424
3:  C   c     -0.5955292
```

And of course what I want is:

```
> y
   v1 v21 v22          v
1:  A       a  0.3316665
2:  B   b      0.8470424
3:  C   c     -0.5955292
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
setkey(y, v1, v22)
y[x, v := ifelse(is.na(v), i.v, v)]
```

`i.` can be used to distinguish same column name from the `i-expression` `data.table`.

Comment: hmm i should update my example. what i don't want to do is overwrite any original matches.

Comment: @MichaelChirico I see, try the above version then

Comment: this works. any suggestions to possibly save time? not an issue for me, but would be nice to avoid duplicating effort (the first merge hits ~90% of observations)

Comment: @MichaelChirico perhaps you can combine the columns in `y` to begin with? smth like `y[, newcol := v21][newcol == "", newcol := v22]` and then merge that instead

Comment: hmmm no dice for me. in my case, i'm trying to first match people on first/last name; round 2 matches on first name/maiden name. so i don't want to erase the last names.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to @eddi's solution that I'm working with that is somewhat more robust:

```
setkey(y, v1, v22)
y[x[!(v %in% y$v),],v:=i.v]
```

(basically, instead of subsetting `y`, subset `x` via `y` and join the subsetted `x` to `y`.

Comment: Similarly, `setkey(y, v1, v22)`, `setkey(x,v)`, `y[x[J(setdiff(x$v,y$v))],v:=i.v]`